# How can I shorten it logically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code block like below. How can I make this block neat and short without using jquery?

```js
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'margin:15px');
ticketForm.appendChild(mainDiv);

var aLabel = document.createElement('span');
aLabel.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
aLabel.innerHTML = "A Record";
mainDiv.appendChild(aLabel);

var br1 = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(br1);

var aText = document.createElement('span');
aText.innerHTML = "xhttp.responseText";
mainDiv.appendChild(aText);

var br2 = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(br2);

var wwwLabel = document.createElement('span');
wwwLabel.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
wwwLabel.innerHTML = "WWW Record";
mainDiv.appendChild(wwwLabel);

var br3 = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(br3);

var wwwText = document.createElement('span');
wwwText.innerHTML = "xhttp.responseText";
mainDiv.appendChild(wwwText);

var br4 = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(br4);

var ftpLabel = document.createElement('span');
ftpLabel.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
ftpLabel.innerHTML = "FTP Record";
mainDiv.appendChild(ftpLabel);

var br5 = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(br5);

var ftpText = document.createElement('span');
ftpText.innerHTML = "xhttp.responseText";
mainDiv.appendChild(ftpText);
```

Comment: You are not using jquery...You don't need create a separate variable for each element, just reuse one variable. Also, avoid using inline styles, use CSS instead.

Comment: If you're creating lots of elements dynamically like this, it's usually poor design. The elements should generally be in an HTML document. If you need to create new elements dynamically, do it by cloning a template that's in HTML.

Comment: Why are you quoting `xhttp.responseText`? If this is being done in an AJAX callback function, that should be an ordinary variable, not a string literal.

Comment: Please not that this question may be more suitable at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it in one larger `innerHTML`?

```js
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'margin:15px');

mainDiv.innerHTML = `
<b>Anything you want</b> can be here!
<br />
<div style="color: red">Div with styling</div>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning a full-scale web development framework, but for your purposes maybe you don't need that. You could try something like this:

```js
const BOLD_STYLE = 'font-weight:bold';
const HTTP_INNER_HTML = 'xhttp.responseText';

const addElement = (elementType, parentElement, options) => {
    const element = document.createElement(elementType);
    if (options.style) {
        element.setAttribute('style', options.style);
    }
    if (options.innerHTML) {
        element.innerHTML = options.innerHTML;
    }
    parentElement.appendChild(element);
    return element;
};

const mainDiv = addElement('div', ticketForm, { style: 'margin:15px' });
addElement('span', mainDiv, { style: BOLD_STYLE, innerHTML: 'A Record' });
addElement('br', mainDiv);
addElement('span', mainDiv, { innerHTML: HTTP_INNER_HTML });
addElement('br', mainDiv);
addElement('span', mainDiv, { style: BOLD_STYLE, innerHTML: 'WWW Record' });
addElement('br', mainDiv);
addElement('span', mainDiv, { innerHTML: HTTP_INNER_HTML });
addElement('br', mainDiv);
addElement('span', mainDiv, { style: BOLD_STYLE, innerHTML: 'FTP Record' });
addElement('br', mainDiv);
addElement('span', mainDiv, { innerHTML: HTTP_INNER_HTML });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a stylesheet with CSS rules on the `mainDiv` will make the styles easier to understand and less verbose.

There's also no need for `document.createElement` in some cases - simply setting the `innerHTML` of the container can work fine, or `insertAdjacentHTML`.

```
.main-div {
  margin: 15px;
}
.main-div > .bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
ticketForm.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<div class="main-div">
  <span>A Record</span>
  <br>
  <span>xhttp.responseText</span>
  <br>
  <span class="bold">WWW Record</span>
  <br>
  <span>xhttp.responseText</span>
  <br>
  <span class="bold">FTP Record</span>
  <br>
  <span>xhttp.responseText</span>
</div>
`);
```

I'd also recommend using `<div>`s or styling rules instead of `<br>`s if at all possible - having so many `<br>`s is quite a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Your method could re-use the same variable for each element

```js
var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'margin:15px');
ticketForm.appendChild(mainDiv);

var node = document.createElement('span');
node.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
node.innerHTML = "A Record";
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('span');
node.innerHTML = "xhttp.responseText";
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('span');
node.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
node.innerHTML = "WWW Record";
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('span');
node.innerHTML = "xhttp.responseText";
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('span');
node.setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold');
node.innerHTML = "FTP Record";
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('br');
mainDiv.appendChild(node);

node = document.createElement('span');
node.innerHTML = "xhttp.responseText";
mainDiv.appendChild(node);
```

```css
#ticketForm
{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="ticketForm"></div>
```

Or load data from an array:

```js
const templ = [
  ["span", {attr: {style: 'font-weight:bold'}, innerHTML: "A Record"}],
  ["br"],
  ["span", {innerHTML: "xhttp.responseText"}],
  ["br"],
  ["span", {attr: {style: 'font-weight:bold'}, innerHTML: "WWW Record"}],
  ["br"],
  ["span", {innerHTML: "xhttp.responseText"}],
  ["br"],
  ["span", {attr: {style: 'font-weight:bold'}, innerHTML: "FTP Record"}],
  ["br"],
  ["span", {innerHTML: "xhttp.responseText"}],
]

var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'margin:15px');
ticketForm.appendChild(mainDiv);

for (let i = 0; i < templ.length; i++)
{
  const el = document.createElement(templ[i][0]);
  mainDiv.appendChild(el);
  if (!templ[i][1])
    continue;

  const data = templ[i][1];
  for(let d in data)
  {
    if (d == "attr")
    {
      for(let a in data[d])
        el.setAttribute(a, data[d][a]);

    }
    else
      el[d] = data[d];

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ticketForm"></div>
```